# How to limit the graphics card RAM?

Tags: memory, graphics-card

I have used [Video Memory Stress Test](http://mikelab.kiev.ua/index_en.PHP?page=PROGRAMS/vmt_en) and found some problems in graphics card RAM. Sometimes in some applications and games, the graphics looks really weird.

Changing the graphics card involves a lot of paperwork and hassle for some reason (I don't own the computer).

I was wondering if there is a way to limit the addressing of the faulty parts of the graphics card RAM in Windows 7. The card is NVIDIA 9500 GT.

Comment: What are the problems that you noticed that make you think that it's a video card RAM issue?

Comment: Sometimes the objects in a 3D scene has strange textures. Sometimes some vertices of the 3D models goes to infinity. Sometime the graphics in some applications looks like noisy. And that test program I mentioned says so :)

Comment: Can you confirm your GPU drivers are up-to-date with those on the Nvidia website? Can you also download and run [GPU-z](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/SysInfo/GPU-Z/), and check the Sensors page for high temperatures (>70) when running graphically intensive apps?

Comment: This is identical behaviour to the problems we have experienced with ATI 9800XT cards. The thermal pads fitted to the heatsink did not come into proper contact with the memory chips allowing them to overheat and die.    
Another utility available from Misha is his Artifact Locater, if your card fails that test then I would say your memory is definitely the cause.    
It is unlikely that improving the cooling with larger pads, forced air or underclocking will fix it though if you can find an easy/cheap way to do that then go ahead and try.

Comment: @Spectre - I have tried several different drivers including beta drivers. None of them worked. I will check for the temperature and see if it is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such feature; if the card it faulty then that's how it is.

It could be a heat issue, and re-seating heat-sinks might help.

But the answer to your question is: *No, there is no way to limit which bits or bytes of RAM the graphics card uses.*